# How do I open an Excel .xltm file via VBA as a template?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code written in VBA to automate creation of PowerPoints. (Yes, I understand there's a special place in hell for this. Sometimes, however, one must do what is required whether it makes sense or not.)

The process is as follows:

1. Open an Excel template file `MyTemplate.XLTM` creating `MyTemplate1.XLTM`.
2. Update data in `MyTemplate1.XLTM` as appropriate
3. Save `MyTemplate1.XLTM` as `NewFile.XLSM`
4. Open a PowerPoint template file `MyPowerPoint.PPTM`
5. Loop through all the objects/shapes on all the slides in `MyPowerPoint.PPTM` looking for linked shapes

   1. For each linked shape, change `Shape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName` from `MyTemplate.XLTM` to `NewFile.XLSM` (with appropriate gymnastics to link it to the proper location within `NewFile.XLSM`)
6. Save `MyPowerPoint.PPTM` as `NewPPT.pptx`

As the code executes step 5.1, it opens `MyTemplate.XLTM`, adjusts the link location, then closes the file. For *every. single. linked. object.* in the entire PowerPoint presentation. This, obviously, is rather slow. My template file is only 621KB, but loading it from the network takes enough time that I can see the thermometer bar filling in the Excel status bar as it loads. (Yes, I can run with `.ScreenUpdating=False`, and I do, but it still takes time.)

Once I've created the PowerPoint, I can open `NewFile.xlsm`, then open `NewPPT.pptx` and refresh all the links *very* quickly. If I don't open `NewFile.xlsm` first, the refresh all links takes *significantly* longer.

Therefore, I'd like to open `MyTemplate.XLTM` in code *once* prior to step 5.1 so that it doesn't need to load *every time*. However, when I execute

```
Dim TemplateXL as Excel.Workbook
Set TemplateXL = XLObj.Workbooks.Open("MyTemplate.xltm")
```

I get a file called `MyTemplate1.xltm`, and PowerPoint still has to open `MyTemplate.xltm` each time I have to refresh a linked object.

In Windows Explorer, I can right-click `MyTemplate.xltm` then select `open` and I am editing the actual template itself, instead of creating a new document based on that template.

How do I emulate the `Right-Click | Open` functionality within Excel VBA code?

Comment: Do you need to use a template?  Can you instead use a regular .xlsm file (marked as "read only" if you're worried about someone overwriting it) ?

Comment: You know, @TimWilliams, that's a possibility... There is a lot of formatting that was getting lost with my original process, and that led me to using the .XLTM. I may be able to use a .XLSM instead and get the same results. I'll have to look into that. Even if that ends up being suitable for my purposes, I'd be interested in knowing if there is a way to do what I'm asking in this question.

Comment: @TimWilliams - thank you for your suggestion. Converting from the .XLTM to .XLSM format does (after resetting all the links one time to point to the new template file) allow me to open the Excel file once for much quicker re-linking. I would invite you to post that as an answer, and I'll give you an upvote. However, I'd still love to find out if it's possible to do what the title question asks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a minute, so I'll bring closure to this...

I ended up following Tim Williams' suggestion of converting my XLTM macro-enabled Template workbook into an XLSM macro-enabled standard workbook. This allows me to open the workbook in code and update links "very" quickly (in comparison to when it was an XLTM file).

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but anyway, this might work:

`Workbooks.Open("C:path\excel.xltm", editable:=True)`

Comment: Yes, that will open the workbook, but then I don't get a handle to the file so I can do additional work with it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).